# Почему BASH скрипт не сохраняет архив в нужную папку?

Tags: bash

Скрипт который работает как нужно, сохраняет архив в папку backups

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
tar -cvf backups/sfile-autobackup_$date.tar testb
```

Если пишу так то не работает

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_dir="backups"
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
tar -cvf $backup_dir/sfile-autobackup_$date.tar testb
```

Вот что в ответ получаю.

```
/bin/bash ~/backup.sh

tar: backups\r/sfile-autobackup_2018-04-23_21-32-11\r.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Даже если пишу полный путь ( /home/b/b34746883925sc/backup ) всеравно не работает.
Помогите разобратся

UPD: Переносов строк не нашел. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас там перенос строки `\r` затесался откуда-то(во всех переменных причём).. Проверяйте

Comment: Скорее всего, тут дело в разных операционных системах при редактировании скрипта.

Comment: Просто перенаберите эти строчки заново. В LInux переносы - это `\n`, в Win - `\r\n`, в Mac - вроде `\r`, но не суть, могу ошибаться.

Comment: `hexdump -С ~/backup.sh` должен показать лишние байты

Comment: @vp_arth, разобрался. Ответ написал.

Comment: А почему не `rdiff-backup`?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Проблема было в том что я писал этот скрипт сразу на сервере в их редакторе.
Когда скачал файл на комп и ткрил в notepad++ там оказалось вот это, мои старые строки.

Итог. Использовать проверенный редактор надежнее.

```
#!/bin/sh
### System Setup ###
BACKUP=/home/b/b47465sc/backup


### Binaries ###
TAR="$(which tar)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"
FTP="$(which ftp)"


## Today + hour in 24h format ###
NOW=$(date +%Y%m%d) [задаем текущую дату и время, для того чтобы итоговый файл выглядел в виде server-YYYYMMDD.tar.gz]

$TAR -cf $BACKUP/$NOW/testb.tar /home/b/b47465sc/testb/

ARCHIVE=$BACKUP/server-$NOW.tar.gz
ARCHIVED=$BACKUP/$NOW


#!/bin/sh

# задаем переменную DATE. Она будет содержать текущую дату.
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`

# задаем переменную содержащую путь к каталогу с бэкапами.
backup_dir="backups"
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`

tar -cvf $backup_dir/sfile-autobackup_$date.tar home/b/b47465sc/testb
```

Comment: если скрипт будет запускаться не из корня `/`, то относительный путь `home/b/b47465sc/testb` не будет работать. поэтому 1) укажите абсолютный путь 2) или смените рабочий каталог в скрипте на тот, где этот лежит скрипт: `cd "$(dirname "$0")"`